# Simplemap in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I have some troubble to show map in my symfony project.

I use webpack.
In assets folder I have add a folder with the name "map", and in this folder I have 2 files like that:
[assets folder arbo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRAFr.png)

In the webpack file it is like that:
[webpack file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l12f1.png)

And in my page .html.twig this code:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('countrymap') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('mapdata') }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have add the id="map" in the same page, but map is not showing.
No error in console.
Cache clear ok.

What did I do wrong ?
Thanks.